# Authentication Server for App Gateway and Web App sharing the user base with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I'm writing an App Gateway (REST-API) and a Web Application using Spring Boot. I've got a user database containing users and password hashes. Both applications will use the same user database, hence I want to have it in an isolated service. I've looked over https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ which raised the idea to use an Auth Server via OAuth.

I'm quite unsure about the Request Flow for my use case. I think it will go App  -> App Gateway (e.g. Login), which then does a request to /uaa/oauth/token with grant type password(since i got the user credentials). This request must contain client_id and client_secret and should return a token.

1. Is this concept correct for my usecase?
2. If so: How do I have to configure the Auth Server to use the Database instead of Basic Auth? All examples I found have a certain user / pw combination in application.properties
3. What would be the most idiomatic way to delegate Auth via username + pw to the Auth Server?

Edit: I found this to be very helpful: https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot

Now I can do:

`curl -H "Accept: application/json" my-trusted-client@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=password`

How do I wire some user backend into it? As far as I understand the following uses the default Spring Basic Auth settings.

application.yml:

```
security:
  user:
    password: password
```

Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                        "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust").resourceIds("sparklr")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60).and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code").authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "trust").resourceIds("sparklr")
                .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value").and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read").resourceIds("sparklr")
                .secret("secret");
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```